# How can you express a two lognormal distribution in two independent standard normal distributions?

Tags: probability, distributions, lognormal-distribution

Okay so if I have a equation that says the deflection of a beam is

$$
D = \frac{L*F}{R}
$$

Where
D is displacement
L = length
F= force
R= resistance

And I was told that The force and the resistance both have lognormal distribution with

$$
\mu_R = 500\\
\sigma_R = 50\\
\mu_F = 10\\
\sigma_F = 2
$$

How to express D as two independent normal distributions U1 and U2 ?

My working so far is :
$$
F \sim log(10,2^2)\\
R \sim log(500,50^2)\\
log(F) \sim N(10,2^2)\\
log(R) \sim N(500,50^2)\\
x_1=log(F)\\ 
x_2=log(R)\\
\therefore F=e^{x_1} \& ~ R=e^{x_2}\\
U_1=\frac{{x_1}-10}{2} \sim N(0,1)\\
U_2=\frac{{x_1}-500}{50} \sim N(0,1)\\
\therefore F=e^{x_1}=e^{2U_1+10}\\
R=e^{x_2}=e^{50U_1+500}\\
\bf{D}=\frac{e^{2U_1+10} * L}{e^{50U_1+500}}\\
\bf{D}=e^{2U_1-50U_2-490}*L\\
$$

Is this correct way of doing it ? and how would I find the PDF of my function D now ?

Comment: Hint: express $\log(D)$ as a sum or difference of Normal variables.

Comment: Hint2: you've gotten your two normal variables expressed as a linear (affine) function of $(U_1, U_2)$. What is the distribution of such a linear function of normal variables? Then you have an exponential of that resulting random variable.

Comment: @LucasRoberts I don't get your hint tbh. The distribution should be normal then if you take exponential you should be back at lognormal no ?

Comment: @FabianJ yes and judging from your comment, you've understood the hint perfectly. From these pieces of information it should be enough to reconstruct the distribution of displacement ($D$)-provided you know the value of $L$.

Comment: The real issue that needs to be dealt with here is the meaning of the parameters.  In particular, the $\sigma_R$ and $\sigma_F$ cannot possibly be the SDs of the underlying Normal distributions: they are far too large.  They *might* be the standard deviations of the lognormal variables themselves.

Comment: @whuber I don't understand your last comment, so after doing this I got D~log(-45,25.004) so lognormal distribution with mean = -45 and var= 25.004. is this suppose to be right ? also what if I want this as D~N(mu,var) how should I do that ?

Comment: Do a reality check.  We know, for instance, that a Normally distributed variable like $x_2=500+50U_2$ in your final set of formulas has around a 5% chance of being more than two SDs from the mean.  With a mean of $500$ and sd of $50,$ that places the values of $x_2$ outside the interval $[400, 600]$ around 5% of the time.  When you exponentiate those numbers you obtain values for $R=\exp(x_2)$ of $5\times 10^{173}$ and $4\times 10^{260}.$